# Let$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be 2 differentiable functions on $R$. Let $\vec v_1=f(x)i - f’(x)j$ and $\vec v_2=g(x)i + g(x)j$

Tags: calculus, vectors

> Let$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be 2 differentiable functions on $R$. Let $\vec v_1=f(x)i - f’(x)j$ and $\vec v_2=g(x)i + g(x)j$ be any two vectors and let $h(x)$ be the anti derivative of $f(x)g(x)$. If $h(1)=2, h(2)=6, h(4)=1$, then prove that the two vectors are linearly dependent on at least one value of $x$ in $(1,4)$

I have determined that for the two vectors to be linearly dependent we need $h’’(x)=0$ so $h(x)$ needs to be a linear function. However, I am not able to given values to prove the repaired condition. How to proceed?

Comment: you lost interest in your problem!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: Two corrections**
(1):$V_2$ needs to $g(x) \vec i+g'(x_ \vec j$, (2) For tthe final statement to be essentially true the dat for $h(x)$ is not enough. I suggest $h(3)=1, h(4)=2$
.
Then
$$\vec V_1=f(x)\vec i- f'(x) \vec j, \vec V_2= g(x) \vec i+ g'(x) \vec j$$
If $\vec V_1$ $\vec V_2$ are linearly dependent then $\vec V_1=t \vec V_2$
This means
$$-\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=t=\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}\implies [f'(x) g(x)+f(x) g'(x)]=0$$
$$\implies \frac{d}{dx} f(x) g(x)=0=\frac{d^2h(x)}{dx^2}~~~~(1)$$
By LMVT in (1,2), (2,3), (3,4) we get $h'(C_1)=4, h'(C_2)=-5, h'(C_3)=1; C_1<C_2<C_3.$
Next by IVT for $f'(x)$, $h'(C_1)h'(C_2)<0$ and , $h'(C_2)h'(C_3) <0$. So $h'(x)=0$ has at leat two roots  has at least two roots in $(1,4)$. Finally by Role's theorem Eq. (1) ($h''(x)=0$)) has at least one real root in $(1,4).$

Comment: How did you conclude $h’(x)=0$ has two roots? I can see 1 but not getting 2

Comment: @Aditya Please see my edit to make the final statement essentially true.